# A particular form of expectation

Tags: integration, probability-theory, expectation

I am stucked in showing an equality concerning the expectation of a fonction $f \in \mathcal{L}_1(P) , ||f||_1 = \int_R |f(x)|dP(x)$ , where $P$ is a probability measure.

The exercise is the following:

Let $Q_f $ be the inverse functions of the càdlàg function $ t \to \mathbb{P}\left( |f(X)|> t\right)$ , where $\mathcal{L}(X)=P$.

Show that $ ||f||_1 = \int_0^1 Q_f(u)du$

Does anyone has any advice?

Comment: In the first line, do you mean $\|f\|_1 = \int_R |f(x)|dP(x)$?

Comment: Yes, I edited the post.

Comment: You want to use the fact that $\int_Y |f(y)| d\mu(y) = \int_0^\infty \mu(\{|f(y)| > t\}) dt$ and change of variables, $\int_Y g d(f_* \mu) = \int_X g\circ f d\mu$, but some care needs to be taken for the inverse $Q_f$ and I can't seem to work it out right now.